# Get GPS coordinates working for Emulator ,but not device

Tags: java, android, gps

Good day

I am creating a tutoring app for my computer science project and i am having an issue with getting the GPS location. As stated in my title, it works perfectly for the emulator (Toasts the location as well writes to database), but on my phone or every other device I have tried it doesn't even Toast, which means its not even going into the class. I have looked around but cannot find the solution.

Heres my Class getlocation:

```
    package com.example.tutor;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.content.Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;

/**
 * Created by admin on 03-Oct-16.
 */


public class GetLocation2 {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    Activity parent;
    String TutorStudentID;
    int status;


    public GetLocation2(Activity par, String tsi, int i) {

        parent = par;
        TutorStudentID = tsi;
        final int[] count = {0};
        status = i;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) parent.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //  txtLocation.append("\n " + location.getLatitude() + " "+ location.getLongitude());
                if (count[0] == 0) {

                    if (status == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(parent.getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Long: " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        tutor_checkin connect2server = new tutor_checkin(parent, TutorStudentID, "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Long: " + location.getLongitude());
                        connect2server.execute();
                    }
                    if (status == 1) {
                        Toast.makeText(parent.getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Long: " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        tutor_checkout connect2server1 = new tutor_checkout(parent, TutorStudentID, "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Long: " + location.getLongitude());
                        connect2server1.execute();
                    }

                    count[0]++;
                }

                Toast.makeText(parent.getApplicationContext(), "Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Long: " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
                //  onLocationChanged();


            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                parent.startActivity(intent);



            }
        };
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parent, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parent, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                parent.requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                        , 10);
                return;
            }
        } else {

            //  if(count ==0) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);


            // count++ ;
            // }

            //  configureButton();
            // btnLocation.performClick();
            //  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);

        }

    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // int count = 0 ;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 10:
                // if(count == 0 ) {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parent.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parent.getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        // TODO: Consider calling
                        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                        //                                          int[] grantResults)
                        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                        return;
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);
                      //  count++;

                    }
                //}


                //  configureButton();
        }

    }

}
```

Heres where I am calling it from (Its from a CardViewAdapter)

```
eventViewHolder.Checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String sText = eventViewHolder.Checkin.getText().toString() ;



                if(sText.toString().equals("Check in"))
                {
                    eventViewHolder.Checkin.setText("Check out");
                    new GetLocation2(H, Sessions.get(i).sessionID,0);



                }
});
```

Comment: What version is your phone running? You have to explicitly handle permission requests for certain permissions in Marshmallow+

Comment: Tested API 17, and 23. When you say explicitly you mean what exactly?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I have these request permissions in my Getlocation class ' parent.requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                        , 10);
                return;'

Comment: Do you have "Location" turned on on your device? I think if that is turned off it won't permit _anything_ to see your location. I _think_.

Comment: @zgc7009 I am continuously checking google maps to see if my GPS is on, and it is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're missing the ['uses-permission' declaration in the AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

As described in the [requesting permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) documentation,

> **On all versions of Android, your app needs to declare both the normal and the dangerous permissions it needs in its app manifest**, as described in Declaring Permissions. However, the effect of that declaration is different depending on the system version and your app's target SDK level:
>
> If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.
>
> If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: **The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running**. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

Comment: When i click the "Check in" button , it does request to accept permissions , after accepting , nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);
```

instead of :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, locationListener);
```

Does the phone has an fix?, can it get the location from GPS?, try using the app outside the house so you are sure the GPS gets an fix. Is the location-service enabled on the phone?

And besides asking for runtime permissions, you also need to add the permissions to the manifest file.

Comment: Unfortunately that line didnt help. Yes all permissions are enabled as well the location services. Permissions are also in manifest(Course and fine location). The baffling thing is that it doesnt even show the Toast that is in the onLocationChanged. On the emulator , it toasts 0.0 if theres no location set, but on the device, nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that where you have the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method, it's not overriding any methods from the superclass, so it will never be called.

This method override needs to go in the Activity.

It's good practice to use the `@Override` annotation for method overrides.
If you put one over `onRequestPermissionsResult()` where you have it currently, you should see something like this:

[image]

In order to fix it, first create an instance variable to keep track of the GetLocation2 reference:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GetLocation2 getLoc2;
    //............
```

Then assign the `getLoc2` reference:

```
eventViewHolder.Checkin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String sText = eventViewHolder.Checkin.getText().toString() ;
            if(sText.toString().equals("Check in"))
            {
                eventViewHolder.Checkin.setText("Check out");
                getLoc2 = new GetLocation2(H, Sessions.get(i).sessionID,0);
            }
        });
```

Then move the `onRequestPermissionsResult()` method to the Activity, and instead of calling `requestLocationUpdates()` directly, call a new public method that you will define in the GetLocation2 class:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }

                if (getLoc2 != null) {
                    getLoc2.requestLocations();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Lastly, define the `getLocations()` method in the GetLocation2 class:

```
public void requestLocations() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parent, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(parent, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,5000,0,locationListener);
}
```

Comment: Good day Thank you so much for your reply, I feel like we are almost there now , there however one issue , I am calling the get Location function in a cardview adapter , adding the OnRequestPermissionResult(with the @Override) gives the same error as you have shown above , I am calling the CardViewAdapter from the HomeFragment , I tried sending through the getLoc2 to the adapter from the Fragment , However nothing happens ,No Toast from the emulator either